# include jar of one module to another

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, netbeans-8

I have maven projet with this architecture:

```
++parent-project
    +module-a
    +module-b
```

module-b is a web application. it will be run on Jboss AS 7.1.1. I'm using netbeans IDE.

Now `module-b` depend on `module-a`. this is a porm section of `module-b`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

When i build the war file of `module-b`, `module-a` is not present to lib folder ( in war file. i open it with archive explorer ). therefore JBoss return `ClassNotFoundException`.

I'm tried differends scope ( compile , provided , runtime , test ). But nothing.

Please how can i solve this.

Comment: Questions: 1) did you (have to) mention `module-a` version? 2) What is `module-a` packaging? a jar?

Comment: 1) i'm not mentioned version. 2) yes, module-a is a jar

Comment: 3) Does `module-a` appears in your `mvn dependency:tree` ?

Comment: in netbeans, YES.

Comment: How are you building the war file of module b? Is the packaging of module b set to war in the module b POM?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should try to see how does it work in "pure" maven, without the IDE at all (NetBeans). So my answer will be based only on maven knowledge:

A couple of facts:

1. Module b has to have the following in pom: `<packaging>war</packaging>` This will instruct maven that you really want to get a war from this module.
2. When packaging WAR is specified in some pom, maven will take all the dependencies defined in this pom and will put them into the WEB-INF/lib folder of the war. Automatically. Of course, you can customize the output, but its more advanced stuff (see Maven WAR plugin if required)
3. All the dependencies have to be defined with group id, artifact id, and version at least. So make sure that you have the dependency on module a with version. There is no need to fiddle with scopes in this case. The default scope (if you don't specify a scope at all) is 'compile' which is fine.
4. Go to the directory of module b and from within the directory type: `mvn dependency:tree`. Once its done, please carefully observe the output, especially make sure that module a is listed (with a correct version) in a tree.

Sometime to make sure that no stale artifacts reside in the local m2 repository you might want to delete all the jars of your project from there and then execute the `mvn package` command again. The war has to be created in `module b/target` - and this is the WAR you should check out.

Note, all these steps are done without any interaction with NetBeans at all.